# UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities & XCode

Tags: ios, restrictions

So, I'm submitting an app that should only run on the iPhone 4, 4s, 5 & iPod Touch 5G, so I decided to add "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities" to my plist with the "camera-flash" value which would accomplish that.

However, I'm still able to download and run a build with that restriction from TestFlight - is RequiredDeviceCapabilities only enforced at the app store level? Or am I doing something wrong here?